# NodeJs create new array from MySQL query result

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays, node.js

In my `NodeJs` project i want to create new `array` form `MySQL` query result.

**This is my result:**

```
[
    {
        "availabilityId": 1,
        "dayName": 1,
        "fromTime": "05:30:00",
        "toTime": "10:00:00"
    },
    {
        "availabilityId": 2,
        "dayName": 1,
        "fromTime": "10:30:00",
        "toTime": "06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "availabilityId": 3,
        "dayName": 2,
        "fromTime": "16:30:00",
        "toTime": "22:00:00"
    }
]
```

In this result two data's `dayName` are same.

This is my expected result

```
[
    {   
        "dayName": 1,
        "time":[
            {
                "availabilityId": 1,
                "fromTime": "05:30:00",
                "toTime": "10:00:00"
            },
            {
                "availabilityId": 2,
                "fromTime": "10:30:00",
                "toTime": "06:00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "dayName": 2,
        "time":[
            {
                "availabilityId": 3,
                "fromTime": "16:30:00",
                "toTime": "22:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My code:

```
CubbersAvailability.findAll(
    {
        where:{
            cubbersId:1,
            userId:2
        },
        attributes:['availabilityId', 'dayName', 'fromTime', 'toTime']
    }
).then(availabilityList =>{
    res.send(availabilityList);
    // code for create new array
}).catch(error=>{
    res.status(403).send({status: 'error', resCode:200, msg:'Internal Server Error...!', data:error});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough, but very specific.

```js
const source = [
    {
        "availabilityId": 1,
        "dayName": 1,
        "fromTime": "05:30:00",
        "toTime": "10:00:00"
    },
    {
        "availabilityId": 2,
        "dayName": 1,
        "fromTime": "10:30:00",
        "toTime": "06:00:00"
    },
    {
        "availabilityId": 3,
        "dayName": 2,
        "fromTime": "16:30:00",
        "toTime": "22:00:00"
    }
];

function createNewArray(source) {

  let output = [];

  source.forEach(entry => {

    let dayName = entry.dayName;
    let time = {
      "availabilityId": entry.availabilityId,
      "fromTime": entry.fromTime,
      "toTime": entry.toTime
    };

    if (output[dayName] === undefined) {
      output[dayName] = {
        "dayName": entry.dayName,
        "time": []
      };
    }

    output[dayName].time.push(time);

  });

  output.shift(); //shouldn't be needed, but since [0] is empty, necessary.

  return output;

}

console.log(createNewArray(source));
```

Comment: Thanks for your code it working but result came linke this https://ibb.co/bHTkw6w

Comment: But see my expected result if same `dayName` means that data in same array

Comment: are you there bro

Comment: Corrected the structure, but for some reason, it adds a `undefined` in the beginning, guessing cause there is no `0` in the array, just make a check if the entry is `undefined` and skip it if it is.

Comment: Now it's working bro but top of the result get `undefined`

Comment: Yea, since you have no dayName: 0, added a .shift(), to remove first entry, shouldn't be needed thou. *god, I need sleep*